# How to solve this Graph connectivity Problem?

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm

Recently I faced below Question in an interview , which I was unable to answer, Can anyone please help me to find an algorithm to solve it? Which graph concept I should apply to solve it?

Given Number of routers and links between routers.
Write an alorithm to identify all such routers that need to be connected to network all the time

Input : **6,5** (where 6 is num of routers and 5 is number of links)
 **[(1,2), (2,3), (3,4), (4,5), (6,3)]**

Output: Expected return value
**2 3 4**

Answer (score 2):

This problem essentially boils down to finding all the [articulation points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biconnected_component) of the graph. An articulation point in a graph is a node that, if removed, disconnects the graph, which is precisely what you're looking for.

This is a well-studied problem that has a nice solution using depth-first search. Hopefully this gives you the right terms to search for!

Answer (score 1):

Your graph is 
graph G {
"1"--"2"
"2"--"3"
"3"--"4"
"4"--"5"
"6"--"3"
} in [GraphViz](http://www.webgraphviz.com/)
which generates

[image: graph]

so {2, 3, 4} are the nodes with more than one distinct edge.

If the input is guaranteed to not have duplicate edges, then any node which appears more than once in the input is required.

If the input is not guaranteed to not have duplicate edges, you have to tally distinct edges for each node and choose the nodes which do not have only one distict edge.

Comment: I don't believe it's the case that anything that appears more than once is necessary. What if everything links in a ring?

Comment: Thanks @Pete for clarification , can u write an algorithm for this, and one input for problem which might help you.
[(1,2), (1,3), (2,3), (3,4), (4,5), (4,6), (5,6),(5,7),(6,7), (7,8),(8,9),(8,10),(9,10)]